# Query string not sending values in HeaderTemplate

Tags: asp.net

I am using Itemtemplate and headertemplate inside datalist. But in case of headertemplate it is not sending query string value to other page

following is the code of datalist for brandwise.aspx

```html
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" >
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                         <a href='pc1.aspx?<%# Eval("categoryId","cid={0}") %>' style="text-decoration:none">
  ALL BRANDS
                                </a>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    
                    <ItemTemplate>
                       
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                
                        <a href='brandwise.aspx?<%# Eval("categoryId","cid={0}") %>&<%# Eval("brandId","bid={0}") %>' style="text-decoration:none">
   <%# Eval("brandName", "{0}") %>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                       
                    </ItemTemplate>
                   
                  
                </asp:DataList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" SelectCommand="select distinct b.brandName,p.categoryId,b.brandId from Brand1 b, Category c, Product1 p where b.brandId = p.brandId and p.categoryId = c.categoryId and p.categoryId = @cid;">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="cid" QueryStringField="cid" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The problem is in following header template

```html
 <HeaderTemplate>
                         <a href='pc1.aspx?<%# Eval("categoryId","cid={0}") %>' style="text-decoration:none">
  ALL BRANDS
                                </a>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
```

because when it redirect to pc1.aspx in the browser window it displays

```html
http://localhost:3492/pc1.aspx?
```

Which means it does not take into account query string value and categoryId is the name of the column.
I am basically making an e-commerce website for my project. In this code I am trying to display the brands for a given category as in amazon. For e.g the category maybe "mobile" and brands may be samsung,apple,nokia. So if user clicks on a particular brand it displays mobiles for that brand onlys. AND i also need to include one "ALLBRANDS" option clicking on which displays all the brands. Is there any why i can do so??? 
Plz dont try to run it. It wont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HeaderTemplate` is common for all elements and is rendered only once for `DataList` control, it's not tight to data source so I'm afraid your code doesn't make sense.

If you need content of `HeaderTemplate` be item data related, then you need to put it on `ItemTemplate`

Comment: i used that conecpt. also i used two item templates but in that case the second item template values which currently i am putting in my headertemplate was not displaying

Comment: @Ashish Chopra: why can't you put both contents inside the same `ItemTemplate`?

Comment: becase i donot want to repeat the anchor tag with ALL BRANDS VALUE

Comment: @Ashish Chopra: you don't want to repeat the anchor tag but on your example querystring takes `categoryId` from current item... I understand that you want to display this anchor tag once per category

Comment: I am basically making an e-commerce website for my project. In this code I am trying  to display the brands for a given category  as in amazon. For e.g the category maybe "mobile" and brands may be samsung,apple,nokia. so i also need to include one "ALLBRANDS" option clicking on which displays all the brands. Is there any why i can do so???

Comment: @Ashish Chopra: You'll need to have one extra data list inside `ItemTemplate`, nested data lists. In any case, I recommend you to use a `Repeater`. It's not that `DataList` won't work but it's not the best tool for the job. Google nested repeaters to get working examples

Comment: isn't there any property like "no-repeat" which i can attach with the "all brands" anchor tag so that it displays only once

Comment: @Ashish Chopra: you would overcoplicate it. Nested controls is the way to go. I'm sure you can do it without repeating but it's not easy to implement, haven't thought on anything in particular though